# Why can i not create a proper flexbox when data come from Javascript and displayed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Good morning and thank you in advance for reading it! I'm really stuck for 4-5 hours experimenting with many solutions. I changed the javascript html const multiple times, the queryselector that you can see in order to select other items, the css of course to try to make it work and this is one of my last tries before posting here.

So what's the plan? It's my 4th day into javascript learning and I want to insert 20 or 30 products(Imagine that these are only 3) in a website product page. Every product should be displayed in a small box and every box should have the image, the title, the price and a link to add to the basket. And the maximum of elements displayed at a time should be 4, and then wrap. And again and again if the products are more. Firstly, the whole container expands out of the page some times, it never wraps and many other problems. Let's say that mine is a ridiculously simpler version as I am doing it to learn, but I am thinking of something like this. Without all the functionality of course: https://arredo.qodeinteractive.com/lightning-home/

```
    <div class="product-center-container">
    <div class="product">   
            <img class ="p_image" src="">
            <h1 class="p_title">Title</h1>
            <h4 class="p_price">Price</h4>
            <a href="basket.html">Add to basket</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
const aaa = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "vvsdvsweqe",
  p_price: 133,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const bbb = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "dwadawdwadawdadawdwad",
  p_price: 34,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ddd = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "dwadawdwadawdwad",
  p_price: 3333,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ccc = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1Gru7lAKz-DduL6PegJ1YN6NUBMRKcuYUZg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "sadwadawdawdawdawdawda",
  p_price: 323,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ggg = {
  p_image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg",
  p_title: "Agwadawda",
  p_price: 1333,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};

const products = [
  aaa, bbb, ddd, ccc, ggg
];



const containerProducts = document.querySelector(".product-center-container");
const displayProducts = function(products) {
  containerProducts.innerHTML = "";

  products.forEach((element) => {
    const html = `
    <div class="product">   
    <img class ="p_image" src="${element.p_image}">
    <h1 class="p_title">${element.p_title}</h1>
    <h4 class="p_price">${element.p_price}</h4>
    <a href="basket.html">Add to basket</a>
    </div>
    `;

    containerProducts.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html);
  });
};
displayProducts(products);
```

```css
.product-center-container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.product {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="product-center-container">
  <div class="product">
    <img class="p_image" src="">
    <h1 class="p_title">Title</h1>
    <h4 class="p_price">Price</h4>
    <a href="basket.html">Add to basket</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you really mean to use `"beforebegin"`? I guess you meant to use `"afterbegin"`.

Comment: @WaisKamal Yes i tried it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that the products are not placed inside the container. Therefore `display: flex;` has no effect on the products. To fix this, each product must be added as a child of the container.

```js
// ...
products.forEach((element) => {
    // create a new div
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    // add css class
    div.className = "product";
    // place the content inside the div
    div.innerHTML = `
    <img class ="p_image" src="${element.p_image}">
    <h1 class="p_title">${element.p_title}</h1>
    <h4 class="p_price">${element.p_price}</h4>
    <a href="basket.html">Add to basket</a>
    `;

    // add the product div as child of the container
    containerProducts.appendChild(div);
});
// ...
```

Another problem is that a fixed width is used. If a fixed width is used for the product div, then it does not wrap after 4 elements, but whenever there is not enough space to display another element. So to display only a maximum of 4 elements per row, the width must be set as a percentage if the container does not have a fixed width.

```css
.product {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
  
  width: 25%; /* 25% => 1/4 of the available space, no space between each item */
  
  /* ... */
}
```

If there should be some space between each product, then this can be defined via the margin property. However, the margin must then be subtracted from the width of each element, e.g.:

```css
.product {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px); /* second value => 2*margin */
  
  /* ... */
}
```

Everything combined:

```js
const aaa = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "vvsdvsweqe",
  p_price: 133,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const bbb = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "dwadawdwadawdadawdwad",
  p_price: 34,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ddd = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQFTsOIvvpkzFMvb1VEEUq9j3SPD6OKIowCg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "dwadawdwadawdwad",
  p_price: 3333,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ccc = {
  p_image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1Gru7lAKz-DduL6PegJ1YN6NUBMRKcuYUZg&usqp=CAU",
  p_title: "sadwadawdawdawdawdawda",
  p_price: 323,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};
const ggg = {
  p_image: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg",
  p_title: "Agwadawda",
  p_price: 1333,
  p_details: "DDDDDDDDloremw adan wdaniw dnwaidn aiwdn aiwn dian ianwdi jwand andjn waidn waidnw wajond ajownd ainwdi andoawndnwqoind wioqnd oqin"
};

const products = [
  aaa, bbb, ddd, ccc, ggg
];


const containerProducts = document.querySelector(".product-center-container");
const displayProducts = function(products) {
  containerProducts.innerHTML = "";

  products.forEach((element) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "product";
    div.innerHTML = `
    <img class ="p_image" src="${element.p_image}">
    <h1 class="p_title">${element.p_title}</h1>
    <h4 class="p_price">${element.p_price}</h4>
    <a href="basket.html">Add to basket</a>
    `;

    containerProducts.appendChild(div);
  });
};
displayProducts(products);
```

```css
.product-center-container {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.product img {
  /* fit image to container */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product .p_title {
  /* fit title to container */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="product-center-container"></div>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! I managed to fix it while waiting for an answer but I really appreciate it :)